# How to Enable touch for qt app

Tags: linux, qt, embedded-linux, evdev

we running a boot2qt image @ apalis-imx6/Ixora bord from Toradex.

=>   Linux b2qt-apalis-imx6 3.14.52-v2.6b2.1+g9f2723e #1 SMP Wed Mar 29 17:08:54 CEST 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

and connect a easyMaxTouch Display/Touch Modul from Data Modul (pcap).

How can i start my QT App with libevdev/libinput/tslib support? Which QT defines i have to export ?

best regards

lars

Comment: touch ist linked to /dev/input/touchscreen0

Comment: Have you checked Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html#touch ?

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes i checked this and only the tslib version worked but this is for resistive touch screens. the boot2qt image provide a  libinput - 1.4.1-r0 package which contains a event test bin called libinput-debug-events . running this detect all touch events, so i think i missed to set some QT defines. is there a list of all QT_QPA_* defines

Comment: Not to my knowledge. If you use boot2qt doesn't that means that you have tech support from The Qt Company? They should know.

Comment: A boot2qt image does not necessarily mean he is a user of the "Qt for Device Creation" product. Nowadays there is also meta-boot2qt which the open source underpinning of the commercial product.